# Spring Security LDAP Login Bad Credentials

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-security, spring-ldap

I'm trying to use the spring security to connect with LDAP but it always show Bad credentials problem.
 I think maybe there is something wrong with my code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.debug(true);
    }
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.ldapAuthentication().userDnPatterns("sAMAccountName={0},OU=SupportUsers,OU=Users,OU=company,DC=ad,DC=company,DC=com,DC=pl")
            .contextSource(contextSource()).passwordCompare().passwordAttribute("userPassword");
    }
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin();
        http.csrf().disable(); //Vaadin already have built in csrf
    }
    @Bean
    public LdapContextSource contextSource () {
        LdapContextSource contextSource= new LdapContextSource();
        contextSource.setUrl("ldap://192.168.2.2:389");
        contextSource.setBase("dc=ad,dc=company,dc=com,dc=pl");
        contextSource.setUserDn("CN=lister,OU=SupportUsers,OU=Users,OU=company,DC=ad,DC=company,DC=com,DC=pl");
        contextSource.setPassword("examplePassword");
        contextSource.setAnonymousReadOnly(false);
        contextSource.setPooled(true);
        contextSource.afterPropertiesSet();
        return contextSource;
    }
}
```

I can't find a bug in a code, maybe I'm doing something in a wrong way. Here is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>pl.com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>LDAPSpringInitializr</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>LDAPSpringInitializr</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <vaadin.version>8.0.5</vaadin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-ldap</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Did I made something wrong? Maybe there is a problem with password encoding? Greetings, Rafał

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    auth.ldapAuthentication().userSearchFilter("(sAMAccountName={0})")
    .contextSource(contextSource());
}
```

It works, I've just changed that method.

Comment: Thanks a lot bro, I was hours stuck

Comment: Mate, I have been stuck for the last two days, no joking. This saved my life :)